# mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean

Tags: php

good day, I am encountering the said error above and i cant find the proper script for this.. but the are the line where the error occurs..

```
$db = mysql_connect($mysql_server, $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
   mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $db);
   $sql = "SELECT password, fullname, active FROM ".$mysql_table." WHERE username = '".$_POST['username']."'";
   $result = mysql_query($sql, $db) or trigger_error ( mysql_error ( ) );
   if ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
      if ($crypt_pass == $data['password'] && $data['active'] != 0)
      {
         $found = true;
         $fullname = $data['fullname'];
      }
      else die(mysql_error());
   }
   mysql_close($db);
   if($found == false)
   {
      header('Location: '.$error_page);
      exit;
   }
   else
   {
      session_start();
      $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
      $_SESSION['fullname'] = $fullname;
      $rememberme = isset($_POST['rememberme']) ? true : false;
      if ($rememberme)
      {
         setcookie('username', $_POST['username'], time() + 3600*24*30);
         setcookie('password', $_POST['password'], time() + 3600*24*30);
      }
      header('Location: '.$success_page);
      exit;
   }
```

btw, this is a login form..

Thank you!

Comment: 20 times a day, someone asks this very question!

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 0):

`($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))`

If $result is an empty data set, this error is triggered.
Check if the number of rows returned is >0 before doing this.

[**mysql_num_rows**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) is what you should use to check rows returned before trying to put it into an array.

**Also, `mysql_*` extensions are discouraged. Move to [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php), for new projects.**